# FastAPI Global Limit & developer Tokens

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm currently trying to move my API from Flask to FastAPI and I'm struggling to add rate limiting that would fit my needs.

I managed to get a global rate limit working using slowapi but not the developer token that should bypass the rate limit entirely.

So basically I need a global rate limit and a "token" query parameter that would bypass the rate limit.

Current code(Flask & Flask-Limiter)

```
limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["120/minute"],
    default_limits_exempt_when=lambda: request.args.get('token') in config["tokens"]['devel']
)
```

Current code (FastAPI & Slowapi) -Global rate limit only

```
limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, default_limits=["120/minute"])
    app.state.limiter = limiter
    app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)
    app.add_middleware(SlowAPIMiddleware)
```

I have already tried a similar implementation of this but it didn't work.

Note: I never used FastAPI before.

Answer (score 1):

**slowapi** does have an `exempt_when` parameter in the [`limit` decorator](https://slowapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#:%7E:text=methods%3DNone%2C%20error_message%3DNone%2C-,exempt_when,-%3DNone%2C%20override_defaults%3DTrue)):

> exempt_when: function returning a boolean indicating whether to exempt the route from the limit

In FastAPI there is no request context concept like flask's [request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/reqcontext/).

To access the `Request` object, add a middleware that uses [`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html):

```py
from contextvars import ContextVar
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, TypeVar

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address)
app = FastAPI()
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)

_request_ctx_var: ContextVar[Request] = ContextVar("request_context")


def get_request_context() -> Request:
    return _request_ctx_var.get()


RT = TypeVar("RT")


@app.middleware("http")
async def request_context_middleware(
    request: Request, call_next: Callable[..., Awaitable[RT]]
) -> RT:
    try:
        request_ctx = _request_ctx_var.set(request)
        response = await call_next(request)
        _request_ctx_var.reset(request_ctx)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        raise e


DEV_TOKENS = ["secret-dev-token"]


def exempt_when_dev() -> bool:
    return get_request_context().query_params.get("token") in DEV_TOKENS


@app.get("/home")
@limiter.limit("5/minute", exempt_when=exempt_when_dev)
async def homepage(request: Request) -> str:
    return "test"
```

References:

- https://github.com/laurentS/slowapi/issues/13
- https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/420

Comment: Not sure why this is not an accepted answer yet, It did save me a lot of trouble and head-scratching. Thanks a lot @Pawel Rubin